# useQuery: Cannot spy the useQuery property because it is not a function

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-hooks, jestjs, react-query

Have a simple useQuery like this

```
  const {
    isLoading, isError, data,
  } = useQuery(['courses', { userId: someUserId }], fetchDataFromBackendServer);
```

in my unit test, i want the useQuery return info from very beginning (there's a reason i want to do that, but that's off the topic)

```
  describe.only('Title', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      jest.clearAllMocks();
      jest.spyOn(React, 'useQuery').mockResolvedValue({ isError: false, isLoading: false });
    }
    ...
  }
```

It gives me:    Cannot spy the useQuery property because it is not a function; undefined given instead

Hot to fix this please ?

Comment: React-Query has [a testing library](https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/testing#_top) and docs on how to use it. Not sure how it interfaces with jest but it's a start, at least.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, React does not provide `useQuery` hook.

I suppose you are using [react-query](https://react-query.tanstack.com)

The second, if you want to use `jest.spyOn(obj, 'method')`, you can't destruct the method from the obj. That means you should use it like `ReactQuery.useQuery()` in your component.

E.g.

```
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import React from 'react';
import * as ReactQuery from 'react-query';

describe('70660790', () => {
  test('should pass', () => {
    jest.spyOn(ReactQuery, 'useQuery').mockImplementation();
    function Test() {
      ReactQuery.useQuery('todos');
      return null;
    }
    render(<Test />);
    expect(ReactQuery.useQuery).toBeCalledWith('todos');
  });
});
```

Test result:

```sh
 PASS  examples/70660790/index.test.tsx (11.646 s)
  70660790
    ✓ should pass (18 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        13.036 s
```

See how `react-query` [exports](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-query/blob/master/src/react/index.ts) hooks in barrel file, we have to use namespace import.

The last, you should not mock `useQuery` hook the third-party package provides, and test the implementation detail. You should keep using the original `useQuery` hook and mock side effect function such as `fetchDataFromBackendServer` (I suppose it's an API call to the remote server). Then you can test what's the output of the component.
See [testing](https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/testing)

Again, don't recommend mock `useQuery`. Mock Implementation is probably inconsistent with the original implementation, This will lead your test to build on the wrong mock Implementation. This causes your test case to pass, but the program is not correct at runtime.

And，test implementation details can also make test cases vulnerable.
A small change in implementation details will cause the test case to fail and you will have to modify the test case.

Comment: This make a lot of sense. Regarding 2nd item, i used jest.spyOn(ReactQuery, 'useQuery').mockReturnValue(), still getting: Cannot spyOn on a primitive value.

why is this ? i changed in both main code and unit test

Comment: btw i insist to mock useQuery to return an immediate value bcz another bug from react-test-library on useEffect, there's a long story just FYI

Comment: @user3552178 Updated answer

Comment: good one, this is the key "import * as ReactQuery", thx a lot !

Comment: @user3552178 Again, you'd better not mock `useQuery`